# How to parse the following JSON in swift ? It has SUCCESS: flag

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

I am using Alamofire to get DataResponse value for a GET request. But I am getting following JSON which I am unable to understand why

```
SUCCESS: {
    data =     (
                {
            "alt_text" = " .... 
              }
           );
    meta = {
          
           }; 
    links = {
          
            };

        }
```

I am unable to understand this JSON format

Comment: What are you printing which results in this object?

Comment: do you have any model or this raw response ?

Comment: apparently this is not the JSON response that you might be getting from GET request. that would be the Dictionary format of the response data or String conversion of that data. Best approach would be to convert into model class using decoder.

Comment: let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            do {
                let decodedObject = try decoder.decode(YOURMODELCLASS, from: responseData)
                completion(decodedObject, nil)
            }
            catch let error {
                print(error)
            }

Comment: I did that, but the SUCCESS: is messing things up! I am getting SUCCESS: in the response of DataResponse<Any> object of Alamofire validation

Comment: @Jok3r This is the sample response! The JSON has SUCESS: at the start and has three fields inside viz, links, meta and data. I am unable to understand how should I treat SUCESS:

Answer (score 0):

The snippet your posted is not the JSON you want from alamofire, the `SUCCESS` is just telling you that the request is successful, and you get your *actual* data by unwrapping it.

I assume the snippet you posted is your `response`, here's an example:

```swift
AF.request(url, method: .get, parameters: [])
    .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
    .responseJSON() { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let json):
            guard let dictJson = json as? [String : Any],
                  let dataDict = dictJson["data"] as? [String : Any]  else { return }
            
            // Handle your json here
            print(dataDict)
        case .failure(let err):
            // Your error handling goes here
        }
    }
```